# FutureBuilder, The getter 'variable' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

Im trying to get the values from the Future object, but vsc always says

```
The getter 'wetter' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'wetter', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'wetter'.dartundefined_getter
```

Thats my code, the Error appears at

> grad = snapshot.data!.wetter

```
void refreshWeather() {
        final Future<Wetter> wetter = Wetterapi.fetchWetter();
    
    FutureBuilder(
        future: wetter,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            grad = snapshot.data!.wetter;
          }
          throw '';
        });
  }
```

The wetter class looks like this

```
class Wetter {
  final String wetter;
  final double temperatur;
  final String wind;

  Wetter({
    required this.wetter,
    required this.temperatur,
    required this.wind,
  });

  factory Wetter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Wetter(
      wetter: json['weather.main'],
      temperatur: json['main.temp'],
      wind: json['wind.speed'],
    );
  }

  String get gewetter {
    return wetter;
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Define the type parameter of `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
//           vvvvvvvv
FutureBuilder<Wetter>(
  future: wetter,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      grad = snapshot.data!.wetter;
    }
    throw '';
  },
);
```